# set boolean value to Realm database when checkbox is checked

Tags: java, android-studio, realm

I have a realm database model which i want to display in arecyclerview,
every row in the database model have a String name,int age and a boolean favourite,when i try to save the boolean value in the RecyclerviewAdapter
by using an interface but i g`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void io.realm.Realm.beginTransaction()' on a null object reference`

this the model

```
public class person extends RealmObject implements{
@PrimaryKey
private String name;
private String job;
private boolean favourite;
private String image;

public AuthorInfo(String image, String job, String name, boolean favoutite) {
    this.image = image;
    this.job = job;
    this.name = name;
    this.favourite = favourite;
}

public AuthorInfo() {
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getJob() {
    return job;
}

public void setJob(String job) {
    this.job = job;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public boolean isFavourite() {
    return favourite;
}

public void setFavourite(boolean favourite) {
    this.favourite = favourite;
}
```

}

this is the interface

```
  public interface ItemClickListener {
void onItemClick(View view,int position);}
```

and this the recyclerview adapter

```
public class PersonAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AuthorAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Realm mRealm;
private RealmResults<AuthorInfo> results;


public PersonAdapter(Context context, RealmResults<AuthorInfo> realmResults) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    results = realmResults;
}


@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    AuthorInfo current = results.get(position);

    holder.name.setText(current.getName());
    holder.job.setText(current.getJob());
    holder.setClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
   mRealm.beginTransaction();
       @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            CheckBox chk= (CheckBox) view;
            if (chk.isChecked()){
                results.get(position).setFavourite(true);
            }
            else if (!chk.isChecked()){
                results.get(position).setFavourite(false);
            }

        }
         mRealm.commitTransaction();
         notifyItemChanged(position)
    });


}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return results.size();
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView name;
    TextView job;
    CheckBox checkbox;

    ItemClickListener itemclicklistener;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        job = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_job);
        checkbox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        checkbox.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener ic) {
        this.itemclicklistener = ic;

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        this.itemclicklistener.onItemClick(view,getAdapterPosition());

    }
}
```

}

so and ideas?!

Comment: Yes. `mRealm` is `null`.

Comment: Also this code won't work with Realm 0.89.0 or newer, because RealmResults are updated delayed (on the next looper event), and you're supposed to use change listeners, which [`RealmRecyclerViewAdapter`](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters/) gives you automatically.

Comment: thank you ,EpicPandaForce i forgot to intialize the mRealm PersonAdapter